# android java mysql : Trouble with Data Loss when moving from Activity to Activity where each one performs an HTTP >php > mysql call

Tags: java, android

**UPDATE**

I am still debugging this issue and still have not found a solution. Here are some more details:

I am not using XML or JSON to retrieve data in my original implimentatin. I have a custom php script that runs from my server, and I have edited the code to parse the database query into a Java string that can easily be parsed into a String Array using the .split(","); command. ex: $return="item 1,item 2,item 3,item 4"; (see the code below)

The data is coming back accurately from the database in Act 3, which returns an array in the format I specified above, then the data only partially comes back for Act 4: the last item on the list does not return data. Then on Act 5 no data is returned and not errors are thrown. I've tried pretty much everything to debug and am at a loss.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

As the title states, I am having trouble in my app where I am navigating from one Activity to another where each one calls to a php, then to a database and returns information. See this diagram:

> - Activity 1: ListActivity, builds a list from local xml
> - Activity 2: ListActivity, builds a list from local xml
> - Activity 3: ListActivity, gets data from a mysql database (HttpClient to
>     php file to db) and uses it to build a
>     list
> - Activity 4: ListActivity, gets data from a mysql database using data from Activity 3 (HttpClient to
>     php file to db) and uses it to build
>     another list
> - Activity 5: Activity, gets data from a mysql database using data from Activity 4 (HttpClient to php
>     file to db) and displays it as a
>     TextView.

The problem is that by the time I get to Activity 5, the data does not return; I get a blank return. I am sending vars to a php script which has been web tested and indeed operates and returns the data correctly. Further, I have alerted all of my data to insure the right vars are being sent to the php files.

Without seeing 5 java docs of code, can any experts, or just anyone, perhaps tell me if I am breaking a cardinal Android / Java rule here?

Added the code for the Activities below::

```
private String KEY_121 = "my php file";

public class db_receive extends ListActivity {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.db_layout);
  String results = getServerData(KEY_121);
  String[] list = results.toString().split(",");
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, list));
}


private String getServerData(String returnString) {
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(ret_att1,ret_data1));
//http post
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    returnString = result;
    return returnString; 
}
```

That is the basic layout of all 3 Activities that send queries to a php file (which grabs data from database) and receivse data, then performs a function. The last Activity is a TextView as opposed to a ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged my issue. Through debugging efforts I realized that the last item on any list that came from the database had an error passing data to the next Activity. The java code was appending a carriage return on the end of the string, which was becomming a string array... Fixing that fixed my issue; works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "cardinal rule" here. Have you debugged the Activity that fails? You can try making the Activity 5 your initial or root Activity (hardcoding the needed parameters) and seeing what happens, maybe you can get a clue on what is going on. Else, we need more info/code.

Comment: Here is what I've done to debug: I've killed the HTTP calls on all but the last Activity, cuz the problem was that by the time you get to the last Act the HTTP calls return nothing even though it is passing the right data from the HTTP calls before it. I replace the calls on Act 3 and 4 with static info mimicing what is in the Database and the last Act works when I do this, meaning it pulls data and displays.

Comment: I have also combined Activities 3 and 4 into one activity by making 2 HTTP calls to the same php script which runs 2 different sets of code. This does the same thing, though. Once I get to the last Activity, which would be Act 4 in this case, the return is empty.

Comment: Also, there is no error in the logcat... wierd. I will post Log anyway in the OP.

Comment: I am beginning to think that the method I am using to HTTP the information in these 3 Activities back-to-back is not the preferred method.  I just tried singling out a layout xml file for each Activity, ensuring that there weren't any elements not being used that were perhaps choking the HTTP calls.

Comment: Ok, to answer your initial question, I have tried hardcoding the info that is being passed along in Activities 3 and 4 above, leaving Act 5 as the only one that actually makes the HTTP call to the php script and it returns the data just fine. This leads me to believe that (a) the data received from Acts 3 and/or 4 is null/incorrect or (b) my process going from one Act to another is degrading the data.   Now I have tested the vars that are returned before using them in the next Act, so I know it isnt (a)...

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you pull the data from the web you should be storing it in a SQLite database.  Then use a CursorAdapter from to bind the data from your database to your list activities.  There is a great video from Google I/O 2010 on building RESTful android apps that explains why you need to do this.

First off you are violating a cardinal rule of android development by not persisting your database immediately in permanent storage. Listen to the google engineer in the video link I posted.

Second you should not make textview the root element in your XML file. You  should put the textview in a linear layout or table layout.

Comment: Am looking into it now. Found the video you're referring to. Thanks, will report my findings and update this thread later.

Comment: What I was doing was storing the retrieved data into String vars and passing them between Activities utilizing the putExtra method. Do you think this is possibly causing the issue?

Comment: Yes persist your data as early as possible.  Store it in the database.  Information in memory can get lost if your activities are stopped or if you are not collecting garbage correctly.

Comment: Here is the video I was talking about. http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=xHXn3Kg2IQE

Comment: Not sure why someone marked down my answer. An explanation would be helpful.  Make sure you are using "org.apache.http".  Also JSON is preferred over xml.

Comment: Had a busy day, so about to get started implimenting SQLite

Comment: I am not using XML or JSON to retrieve data in my original implimentatin. I have a custom php script that runs from my server, I have edited the code to parse the database return a Java string that can easiy be parsed into a String Array using the .split(","); command. ex: $return="item 1,item 2,item 3,item 4";

Comment: The data is coming back accurately from the database in Act 3, which returns an array in the format I specified above, then the data only partially comes back for Act 4: the last item on the list does not return data. Then on Act 5 no data is returned and not errors are thrown. I've tried pretty much everything to debug and am at a loss.